# Acessar aplicação web que esta rodando no apache de um container docker dentro de um servidor linux que eu acesso por ssh

Tags: linux, windows, docker, ssh

Pela minha máquinha windows tenho acesso um servidor linux que está na mesma rede através de um SSH. Preciso acessar uma aplicação web que roda dentro do apache de um container docker que esta nesse servidor, alguma ideia de como fazer isso? Atualmente consigo acessa-la somente pelo navegador do servidor linux e quero acessa-la pela minha máquina windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de mais nada você precisa saber se a rede que esse servidor está, pode ser acessada pela sua máquina direto pelo IP, voĉe pode testar isso dando um ping no ip dela.

Se a sua máquina conseguir dar um ping no servidor, significa que é possivel. Dessa forma, você precisa subir esse container mapeando uma porta que deseja, por exemplo `-p 8000:8000`.

Com o container ativo e a porta mapeada, você pode acessar direto pelo browser digitando o Ip da maquina junto da porta, exemplo, `172.16.108.10:8000`

Answer (score 1):

Depois de acessar o servidor linux por ssh, lista os containers que estão rodando no servidor executando o comando: "docker ps"

verifica o ID do container que você quer acessar e executa: docker exec -it `<id_do_container>` /bin/bash

Comment: O problema que quero acessar a página web que roda pelo apache do container, e não o container em si. Entende ?

Comment: Você precisa subir o container mapeando a porta para alguma porta do servidor, ex: docker run --name `<nome>`  -p 80:80 imagem:latest

Comment: O container vai responder na mesma porta do servidor linux, é só acessar pelo browser do windows, colocar o ip_do_servidor_linux:porta ... ai ele vai direcionar direto para o container

Comment: Vou tentar aqui. Você tem ideia de como posso linkar um container com imagem do apache à um container com a imagem do php? Tenho os dois containers rodando mas acho que preciso ligar os dois de alguma forma

Comment: Aqui tem um tutorial legal de como fazer: https://www.cloudreach.com/blog/containerize-this-php-apache-mysql-within-docker-containers/